# Select Range using column number

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting "Application-defined or object defined error" while passing parameter in range.

If I use below coding, it is running properly without any error.

`With Sheets("BBG").Range("A1:AD1")`

but it I run it with below coding,It is reflecting above error.

`With Sheets("BBG").Range("A1:" & LastColumn & 1)`

Complete coding

```
Dim LastColumn As Long
With Sheets("BBG")
LastColumn = .Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

Set Rng1 = .Find(What:=chck1, _
After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
If Not Rng1 Is Nothing Then
Sheets(2).Activate
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, "N").Value = Rng1.Address
cl = Rng1.Column
Else
End If
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the range as below, I would not recommend using the .Select or Activate method, as it is usually not required, but as I'm not sure what you are wanting to do to the Range, I have as an example shown you how to Select it:

```
Sub foo()
With Sheets("BBG")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).Select
    'Cells(1,1) = Range("A1")
    'Cells(1, LastCol) = Last Column on Row 1
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to search in first row. Complete coding is updated

Comment: @GausShaikh, sorry but your comment is a little ambiguous and your code is also not showing what the variable `chck1` actually holds, so I'm not sure what you are trying to do with it.